# Update MySQL fields w/ update button

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm attempting to update all of the fields displayed from a MySQL table. The delete feature currently works, but I'm not getting any output whatsoever for the update feature. I feel like I'm missing something very basic. Any input is appreciated!

```
    <form action="" method="post">
    <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM customers");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"FirstName\" value=\"" . htmlspecialchars($row['FirstName'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "\"></td>";
    echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"LastName\" value=\"" . htmlspecialchars($row['LastName'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "\"></td>";
    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "</td>";   
    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['address'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['phone'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['product'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['firmware'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['purchase_date'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "</td>"; 
    echo '<td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="email" value="';
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    echo '"><input type="submit" name="delete" value="X"> </td>';
    echo "</tr>";
    echo '<tr><td colspan="9"><input type="hidden" name="email" value="';
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
    echo '"><input type="submit" name="edit" value="Update"></td></tr>';
    }
    echo "</table>";

?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $delete = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE email = '$email'";
    if ($con->query($delete) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record deleted successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error deleting record: " . $con->error;
}
if (isset($_POST['edit'])) {

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
    $LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
    $edit = "UPDATE customers SET Firstname = '$FirstName', LastName = '$LastName' WHERE email = '$email'";
    if ($con->query($edit) === TRUE) {
    echo $edit;
        echo "Record updated successfully";
        } else {
        echo $edit;
        echo "Error updating record: " . $con->error;
}
}
$conn->close(); 
}  
?>
</form>
```

Comment: Both your hidden value and submit have the same name attribute.

Comment: Good catch! Updated the values, still not getting any output/changes.

Comment: Update your code with what you are now using.

Comment: I posted an answer below.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I updated the while loop, however I'm still not getting any changes or echo for the $edit.

Comment: You updated your code and overwrote it without marking it as an edit, potentially getting downvoted for it. I deleted my answer.

Comment: My apologies! I'll correct in the future without overriding.

Answer (score 0):

check your spelling on `conn`
Try this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
// $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM customers");
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM customers");
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"FirstName\" value=\"" . htmlspecialchars($row['FirstName'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "\"></td>";
echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"LastName\" value=\"" . htmlspecialchars($row['LastName'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "\"></td>";
echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "</td>";   
echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['address'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['phone'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['product'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['firmware'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['purchase_date'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "</td>"; 
echo '<td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="email" value="';
echo htmlspecialchars($row['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
echo '"><input type="submit" name="delete" value="X"> </td>';
echo "</tr>";
echo '<tr><td colspan="9"><input type="hidden" name="email" value="';
echo htmlspecialchars($row['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
echo '"><input type="submit" name="edit" value="Update"></td></tr>';
}
echo "</table>";

?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
$email = $_POST['email'];
$delete = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE email = '$email'";
if ($conn->query($delete) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
}
if (isset($_POST['edit'])) {

$email = $_POST['email'];
$FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
$LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
$edit = "UPDATE customers SET Firstname = '$FirstName', LastName = '$LastName' WHERE email = '$email'";
if ($conn->query($edit) === TRUE) {
echo $edit;
    echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
    echo $edit;
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
}
$conn->close(); 
}  
?>
</form>
```

Comment: Changed w/ updated code. Still no updates to database.

Comment: try this on the beginning of your php file.
`ini_set('display_errors',1);`
`ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);`
`ini_set('default_charset','utf-8');`
`error_reporting(-1);`

Do a `var_dump`  on the if construct at the bottom. Add  `or die ($conn->error);` at the end of `$conn->query` Paste results here

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: edit in /var/www/project/view_customers.php on line 2
NULL
Notice: Undefined variable: email in /var/www/project/view_customers.php on line 3
NULL
Notice: Undefined variable: FirstName in /var/www/project/view_customers.php on line 4
NULL
Notice: Undefined variable: LastName in /var/www/project/view_customers.php on line 5
NULL string(6) "Update"

Comment: did you ever get this fixed??

Comment: I did, but I just started back over from scratch. Couldn't find the error and it took less time to recode than to keep looking! Thanks.